# Apply css-background for each element depending on parent's data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am making a rating bar with an element that has a data-rating attribute and it's children with 5 buttons. How can I change background-image of buttons depending on the data-rating attribute? For example if data-rating="3" - select first 3 buttons and change their background.

This is my code:

```
var rating = $('#video-list .children .branch-opened .rating');
rating.each(function() {
  var value = $(this).data('rating');
  var button = $(this).find('button');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="rating" data-rating="4">
<button value="1"></button>
<button value="2"></button>
<button value="3"></button>
<button value="4"></button>
<button value="5"></button>
</div>
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you show your HTML ?

Comment: My bad, edited..

Comment: @ElmarBabayev I have edited my code - `no need of second variable` [it's not a biggy but no need of it ], repaste my code and check plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple code will work for you.

***Updated Code***

```js
var rating = $('.rating');
rating.each(function() {
  var rValue = $(this).data('rating');
  $(this).find('button').slice(0, rValue).addClass('black');
});
```

```css
.black {
  background-color: black;
}

.rating button {
  width: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rating" data-rating="4">
  <button value="1"></button>
  <button value="2"></button>
  <button value="3"></button>
  <button value="4"></button>
  <button value="5"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following (add to your `rating.each` callback function):

```
for (let i = 0; i < value; ++i) {
    $(button[i]).css('background-color', '#abc');
}
```

Edit:
Has to be `$(button[i])` instead of just `button[i]`

Comment: Having this error in console: Uncaught TypeError: button[i].css is not a function

Comment: $(button[i]).css('background-color', '#abc');

Comment: @guest: Yes you're right - always forget that... I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.each` if you're already using jQuery:

```js
var rating = $('.rating').data('rating');
$('.rating .item').slice(0,rating).each(function(index, value) {
  $(this).toggleClass('highlighted');
});
```

```css
.rating {
  display: flex;
}
.item {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.item.highlighted {
  background-color: goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rating" data-rating="4">
  <button class="item" value="1"></button>
  <button class="item" value="2"></button>
  <button class="item" value="3"></button>
  <button class="item" value="4"></button>
  <button class="item" value="5"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

store the rating value and loop through the buttons and check condition if index lesser than rating value then add highlight class on the buttons.

```js
var ratingValue = $('.rating').data('rating');
$('.rating .item').each(function (index, value) {
    if ( index < ratingValue ) {
         $(this).toggleClass('highlighted')
    }
});
```

```css
.rating {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}
.item {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.item.highlighted {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rating" data-rating="3">
  <button class="item" value="1"></button>
  <button class="item" value="2"></button>
  <button class="item" value="3"></button>
  <button class="item" value="4"></button>
  <button class="item" value="5"></button>
</div>
```